# waiting for 2 child processes

Tags: c, pipe, fork, ipc

I'm trying to write a C program in which the main process creates two children: Ping and Pong. Ping prints “ping” followed by a number, and Pong prints “pong” followed by a number, the output must be as the sample run in Figure 1:"

[image]

Here is what I tried to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void main(){

//initializing pipes
int td[2];
int td2[2];

pipe(td);
pipe(td2);

int pid=fork();
if(pid){ //in parent process

int pid2=fork();

if(pid2){// still in parent process



//1st time
int number1;
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d",&number1);

write(td[1],&number1,sizeof(number1));
printf("<>");

write(td2[1],&number1,sizeof(number1));
printf("--");


//2nd time
int number2;
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d",&number2);

write(td[1],&number2,sizeof(number2));
printf("<>");

write(td2[1],&number2,sizeof(number2));
printf("--");

}
else{// in pong process

int number;

read(td2[0],&number,sizeof(number));
printf("pong%d \n",number);

}


}

else{ //in ping process

int number;

read(td[0],&number,sizeof(number));
printf("ping%d \n",number);

}

}//main end
```

explanation: the problem that I faced here, is that the pong gets printed before ping and the parent process doesn't wait for its children to end ( and some output gets printed after root/desktop etc..)

Another problem that I solved, I had read method in the parent process, it fixed my problem because I know that read forces the program to wait until something is written to the pipe, but in this case, we have "write" in the parent process, so the parent is not waiting

I also tried to implementing wait(NULL) but it doesn't seem to work.

any suggestion would be much appreciated

Comment: To control the order of output, you'll need to force each process which is going to output to stdout to wait for its proper turn. The simplest way is usually to have the process waiting for some input like in a pipe from some other process.

Comment: so what you mean is that i have to create a third pipe and add it in the parent process?

Comment: but I'm not expecting any value from the child processes, I'm only sending values from parent to child processes. do I just send the pipe empty to the parent ? or maybe there's a better wait to solve this. I'm not sure. I even tried to implement wait, but it didn't work for me

Comment: my attempt: https://pastebin.com/G07SrfdD

Comment: @pmg appreciate the answer, but do you mind explaining it? since I don't really have much knowledge in C

Comment: @AliZgheib: other than "child blocks on read()" there's really nothing much to explain... set up pipe; fork and 'send child away'; send data to (still blocked) child... the child simply waits until data has been read, then prints it and exits.

Comment: new version, same idea, loop until EOF: https://pastebin.com/xb5KqdjS

Comment: @pmg thank you for your helpful answers, I really do appreciate it a lot, do you mind checking my code out? I have contacted my instructor and he said that this problem can be solved by creating a dummy pipe to force the parent to wait for its child

Comment: I tried to use the for loop, similar to what you used and used 2 dummy pipes to let the parent know when each child ended and follow each print by "<>" if ping child or "--" if pong child but. it's not working for me .. and its printing ping pong <> --. I want something similar to the image mentioned above, here is what I tried: https://pastebin.com/WVFak00m

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you (your instructor) are over-complicating.

So, you want your `main()` to do

```
int main(void) {
    int n;
    //set up pipes and forks
    printf("Enter a number"); scanf("%d", &n);
    // make child1 output " ping<n>\n"
    puts(" <>");
    // make child2 output " pong<n>\n"
    printf(" --\nEnter a second number"); scanf("%d", &n);
    // make child1 output " ping<n>\n"
    puts(" <>");
    // make child2 output " pong<n>\n"
    puts(" -- THE END --");
    // close pipes
    return 0;
}
```

So, except for `"ping"` vs `"pong"` (and using different pipes) the children are absolutely identical. Maybe we can send the string with the number and keep the number of functions down? No ... what about setting the string when creating the process? This sounds better

```
// set up pipes and forks
int pipes1[2], pipes2[2];
pipe(pipes1);
if (fork() == 0) /* child #1 */ child("ping", pipes1);
close(pipes1[0]); // the read end of the pipe belongs to the child
pipe(pipes2);
if (fork() == 0) /* child #2 */ child("pong", pipes2);
close(pipes2[0]); // we are not using the read end of the pipe
```

Now... how do we make a child (children are waiting at their `read()` call) *work*? Well, easy! We write on our end of the pipe

```
scanf("%d", &n); // get value from user
write(pipes1[1], &n, sizeof n); // automatically unblock child1
write(pipes2[1], &n, sizeof n); // automatically unblock child2
```

Repeat these statements for the 2nd user input.

Don't forget to close the write ends of the pipes

```
close(pipes1[1]);
close(pipes2[1]);
```

And that's the `main()` function. What about the function for the children? The `child(char *sign, int pipes[2])`?

```
void child(char *sign, int pipes[2]) {
    close(pipes[1]); // close write end
    int i;
    for (;;) {
        if (read(pipes[0], &i, sizeof i)) {
            printf(" %s%d\n", sign, i); // print and go back to waiting at the read()
        } else {
            break; // exit the loop when read fails
        }
    }
    close(pipes[0]); // no more reading
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // not going back to main()
}
```